# How to get a single character from a string in COBOL?

Tags: arrays, string, variables, cobol

For example if a string is "work" I have to access 3rd character and store it. In C one would do:

```c
char data[5] = "work";
char temp = data[2];
```

Variable `temp` will have the value `'r'`. Now I need to achieve an equivalent in COBOL.

Comment: show us the relevant code from the Procedure-Division and Data-Division.

Comment: When you say particular character, do you mean character position or matching character?  In other words, if the string is "work" do you want "w" to return 1, or do you want 1 to return "w"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first thing to understand is that array indices are zero based in C and 1 based in COBOL.

Next COBOL and C have very differnt ways of representing character strings. In C a string is generally stored
as an array of characters, the end of string is typically represented using a binary zero (null \0). COBOL
has no such convention. Strings are stored in named data items of a specified length. These items are typically
declared under WORKING-STORAGE and have a PICTURE Clause associated with them of type 'X' (there are several other
possibilities for PICTURE clauses but 'X' represents any type of character). For example:

```
01    MY-VARIABLE   PIC X(20).
```

The Working Storage variable called MY-VARIABLE is declared as 20 characters long. It may be assigned a value
in the PROCEDURE DIVISION as follows.

```
MOVE 'work' TO MY-VARIABLE
```

You can then access the various characters of this string (or substrings) using a technique known as
reference modification:

```
DISPLAY MY-VARIABLE(3:1)
```

will display the third character of MY-VARIABLE (1 based indexing), which is 'r'. The first number in parenthesis above (3)
indicates the offset from the beginning of the variable, the second number is the number of characters starting from that position (1).

There are other methods of doing this, such as REDEFINES, where MY-VARIABLE could be redefined as an array of 20 1 character cells. This
is a somewhat outdated mechanism so I would encourage using reference modification to access parts of character strings.

Answer (score 3):

Re-answered. Despite mentioning "string", I think you are talking about what might be termed a "field", a piece of data.

```
01  a-piece-of-data.
    05  first-two-bytes-of-data PIC XX.
    05  third-byte-of-data      PIC X.
    05  fourth-byte-of-data     PIC X.
```

a-piece-of-data is a "group item", which is four bytes long. The "subordinate" definitions allow you to access individual bytes within the four bytes.

It can be done this way:

```
01  a-piece-of-data             PIC X(4).
01  FILLER REDEFINES a-piece-of-data.
    05  first-two-bytes-of-data PIC XX.
    05  third-byte-of-data      PIC X.
    05  fourth-byte-of-data     PIC X.
```

It can be done with "subscripting":

```
01  a-piece-of-data.
    05  FILLER OCCURS 4 TIMES.
        10  a-byte-in-the-piece-of-data PIC X.
```

Now,

```
a-byte-in-the-piece-of-data ( 3 )
```

references the third byte of data.

The subscripting can be done with a literal, as shown, or a data-name (name and storage defined by you in the normal way, must be numeric, best to be binary) or an index name (using INDEXED BY, where you define the name but the compiler defines the storage).

It can also be done with reference-modification, as NealB has shown.

For me, the choice often comes down to "which is clearest for the next person along?".

```
01  WHAREHOUSE-REF.
    05  WHAREHOUSE-CODE    PIC XX.
        88  WHAREHOUSE-HAS-LIFT VALUE "LN" "CV".
    05  WHAREHOUSE-FLOOR   PIC X.
        88  WHAREHOUSE-UPPER-FLOOR VALUE "1" "2".
    05  WHAREHOUSE-BAY     PIC X.

01  W-LIFT-USAGE           PIC X.
    88  W-LIFT-USAGE-NONE  VALUE ZERO.

IF WHAREHOUSE-HAS-LIFT 
AND WHAREHOUSE-UPPER-FLOOR
    MOVE WHAREHOUSE-FLOOR TO W-LIFT-USAGE
ELSE
    SET W-LIFT-USAGE-NONE TO TRUE
END-IF
PERFORM CALC-ROBOT-TIME-TO-BAY
```

Which is the same as (or is it?, you can always check in a manual every time):

```
01  VAR1 PIC X(4).
01  VAR2 PIC X.

IF VAR1 (1:2) = "LN" OR "CV"
AND VAR1 (3:1) = "1" OR "2"
    MOVE VAR1 (3:1) TO VAR2 (1:1) 
ELSE
    MOVE ZERO TO VAR2 (1:1)
END-IF
PERFORM CALC-ROUTINE THROUGH CALC-ROUTINE-EXIT
```

PS. I know about VAR2, but in my experience, that is how many people with no experience who use reference-modification would code it. You'll also see VAR2 (1:), whereas a plain VAR2 is all that is needed. Yes, the names chosen are the type of names which seem to go hand-in-hand with reference-modification and no experience.

Comment: SET W-LIFT-USAGE-NONE TO TRUE means exactly MOVE ZERO TO VAR2 (1:1)? and why need (1:1) after VAR2? can I use MOVE ZERO TO VAR2 only?

Comment: Yes, exactly, but using the SET for the condition-name makes it 100% exactly certain what is going on. The (1:1) for a PIC X of length one is, of course, unnecessary, but since, strictly, all reference-modification is unnecessary, don't expect not to see it. Someone who uses reference-modification isn't going to use it in the best way, are they? So, VAR (1:1) for one byte, VAR (1:7) for seven bytes, and then someone changes the field to eight bytes long, and what happens...?